# How many skus can magento handle?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am about start my project in magento . How many products can be handled by magento with best hosting providers.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25878/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-products-we-can-have-in-a-magento-website

Comment: Magento will handle as many products as you are willing to pay for in infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry to start your online store.

1. Magento can manage so many sku's in your store. But only one sku for particular product.
2. One product belongs to that particular sku. And you can't able to create more than one product with same sku.
3. Please consider and start your online store with out any fear. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Magento can handle as many as product if your hosting support.

So don't worry just start your store on Magento e-commerce.